# Are data dependencies relevant when preparing data for neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, data-science

**Data:** When I have N rows of data like this: (x,y,z) where logically f(x,y)=z, that is z is dependent on x and y, like in my case (setting1, setting2 ,signal) . Different x's and y's can lead to the same z, but the z's wouldn't mean the same thing.

There are 30 *unique* setting1, 30 setting2 and 1 signal for each (setting1, setting2)-pairing, hence 900 signal values.

**Data set:** These [900,3] data points are considered 1 data set. I have many samples of these data sets.
I want to make a classification based on these *data sets*, but I need to flatten the *data* (make them all into one row). If I flatten it, I will duplicate all the setting values (setting1 and setting2) 30 times, i.e. I will have a row with 3x900 columns.

**Question:**
Is it correct to keep all the duplicate setting1,setting2 values in the data set? Or should I remove them and only include the unique values a single time?, i.e. have a row with 30 + 30 + 900 columns. I'm worried, that the logical dependency of the signal to the settings will be lost this way. Is this relevant? Or shouldn't I bother including the settings at all (e.g. due to correlations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are training NN on a sample where each observation is [900,3].
You are flatning it and getting an input layer of 3*900.
Some of those values are a result of a function on others.

*It is important which function, as if it is a liniar function, NN might not work:*

From [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54634/how-do-you-determine-the-inputs-to-a-neural-network):

> "If inputs are linearly dependent then you are in effect introducing
>   the same variable as multiple inputs. By doing so you've introduced a
>   new problem for the network, finding the dependency so that the
>   duplicated inputs are treated as a single input and a single new
>   dimension in the data. For some dependencies, finding appropriate
>   weights for the duplicate inputs is not possible."

Also, if you add dependent variables you risk the NN being biased towards said variables.
E.g. If you are running LMS on [x1,x2,x3,average(x1,x2)] to predict y, you basically assign a higher weight to the x1 and x2 variables.
Unless you have a reason to believe that those weights should be higher, don't include their function.

I was not able to find any link to support, but my intuition is that you might want to decrease your input layer in addition to omitting the dependent values:

From professor A. Ng's ML Course I remember that the input should be the minimum amount of values that are 'reasonable' to make the prediction.
Reasonable is vague, but I understand it so: If you try to predict the price of a house include footage, area quality, distance from major hub, do not include average sun spot activity during the open home day even though you got that data.

#### I would remove the duplicates, I would also look for any other data that can be omitted, maybe run PCA over the full set of Nx[3,900].